# Ruby on Rails: rails g scaffold not generating any views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to use rails g scaffold to generate models, controller, routes, views, etc, but when the command is run, only the model and controller gets generated.

When executed properly it should look like this:

```
rails g scaffold Widget name:string price:decimal
    invoke  active_record
    create    db/migrate/20160722171221_create_widgets.rb
    create    app/models/widget.rb
    invoke    test_unit
    create      test/models/widget_test.rb
    create      test/fixtures/widgets.yml
    invoke  resource_route
     route    resources :widgets
    invoke  scaffold_controller
    create    app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb
    invoke    erb
    create      app/views/widgets
    create      app/views/widgets/index.html.erb
    create      app/views/widgets/edit.html.erb
    create      app/views/widgets/show.html.erb
    create      app/views/widgets/new.html.erb
    create      app/views/widgets/_form.html.erb
    invoke    test_unit
    create      test/controllers/widgets_controller_test.rb
    invoke    helper
    create      app/helpers/widgets_helper.rb
    invoke    jbuilder
    create      app/views/widgets/index.json.jbuilder
    create      app/views/widgets/show.json.jbuilder
    invoke  assets
    invoke    javascript
    create      app/assets/javascripts/widgets.js
    invoke    scss
    create      app/assets/stylesheets/widgets.scss
```

However, mine looks like this:

```
~/Desktop/Actualize/scaffold-app % rails g scaffold Widget name:string price:decimal
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20211104230623_create_widgets.rb
      create    app/models/widget.rb
      invoke  resource_route
       route    resources :widgets
      invoke  scaffold_controller
      create    app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb
      invoke    resource_route
~/Desktop/Actualize/scaffold-app %
```

Any insights on why it's only creating the model and controller would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance it is a Rails API app?

Comment: check if your application is RailsAPI App.
Check in `config/application.rb` 
`api_only = true`

Also check if you have `require 'rails/all'` in `config/application.rb`

Comment: Thanks! The issue was that api_only was set to true and not false. Appreciate it!